# how i sending an auth error from node js to my html client page?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Im new to node js and now im rewriting my website , I scripting the log in page , my issue is to send back to the client page the error message

I tried flash , but not really understand how to use it in the html page...

```
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_login = "'+username+'" AND u_password = "'+password    +'"',  function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                response.redirect('/home');
            } else {
                response.flash('mes','error');
                response.redirect('/log_in');
            }
```

and no idea how to continue in the html page

Comment: are you using plain html?

Comment: yes .. if you have any other suggestions for make it easier id be glad to hear , or if you have a soultion this way..